# re-render form with selected HTML option

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs

I have a form that re-renders if theres any errors, and it re-renders with any valid inputs. I would also like to re-render the form with the selected option in the < select > element but im struggling

```
// controller.js

(req, res, next) => {
   const errors = validationResult(req);

   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     
     res.render("quotes", {
       form: req.body,
       errors: errors.array(),
       yes: 'selected' 
     });
     return; 


// quotes.ejs

  <label for="propertyType">Type of Property</label> <br />
       <select name="propertyType">
         <option value="Building Lot">Building Lot</option>
         <option value="Condo - Appartment">Condo - Appartment</option>
         <option value="Co-op">Co-op (Owned)</option>
         <option value="Duplex">Duplex</option>
         // my poor solutions below
         <option selected value="<%= locals.form? form.propertyType : '' %>"><%= locals.form? form.propertyType : '' %></option>
         <option value="Single Family Home" <% if (locals.errors) { %>  selected="<%-  yes %>" <% } %>>Single Family Home</option>
       </select>
```

my closest solutions are in the last 2 < option > tags (im aware that they might be poor solutions, thats why im here)

any help at all would be greatly appreciated! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to post your from through an AJAX request. That way you don't rerender pages, and you can keep your input data.

Since you choose the re-render option, the most elegant way i can think is through client side javascript.
Fisrt, inside your controller function, return the selected input value

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     res.render("quotes", {
         selected: req.body.propertyType,       
         errors: errors.array()
     });
     ....
```

And inside the quotes.ejs,  you just add a small script

```
// html code
<label for="propertyType">Type of Property</label> <br />
<select name="propertyType">
    <option value="Building Lot">Building Lot</option>
    <option value="Condo - Appartment">Condo - Appartment</option>
    <option value="Co-op">Co-op (Owned)</option>
    <option value="Duplex">Duplex</option>
</select>
// html code

<% if (locals.errors) { %>
// the following will run only if errors exist
<script>
    var selectedInput = "<%= selected %>";
    var options = document.querySelector('[name="propertyType"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (selectedInput === options[i].value) {
            options[i].selected = 'selected';
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
<% } %>
```

The script will run in case of any rendered errors. It loop the options of select input, and check if option value is equal to submitted value. If true, it makes the option selected.

Comment: Is there a way to use the express validator with ajax, or is it a completely different thing? I understand what you're saying though, I'm now looking for a way to avoid rerendering the entire page

Comment: express validator is a library with which you validate and sanitize input data. It has nothing to do with the way you return data to client.